# Escape Unicode character in string - C#, SeleniumWebDriver, VS2017

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2017

I have a code that require to add a Unicode character in at the end of string line. My environment is VS2017. Language is C# (fairly new to me) and I am using selenium webdriver for all my test cases.

The following seems very straight forward but I am having difficulty passing this unicode character. The expected output should have the  character instead of the text shown in here.

```
string updatedMessage = "\u0003";
string start_of_line = "Hello World";

Console.WriteLine(start_of_line + updatedMessage);

Output
Hello World <specialcharacter><specialcharacter><specialcharacter><specialcharacter><specialcharacter>\u0003

Expected output
Hello World\u0003
```

So far, I have tried adding `@"\u0003"`, or `%"\u0003"%` but no luck so far. I appreciate if anyone can suggest a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Those `<specialcharacter>`s don't appear out of thin air; they'll already be at the end of `start_of_line`. If you want to append `u\0003` to the end of your string, you're doing it correctly with the current code (thought the StringBuilder doesn't add anything). Please provide a [mre].

Comment: sorry, It's not letting me add the characters here too. I have edited my question. Please review and let me know.

Comment: Where's the relation to Selenium Webdriver?

Comment: I tried `string updatedMessage = @"\u0003";` and got `Hello World\u0003`. Is this your expected output?

Comment: The expected output is correct but that code is returning ```@<unicode symbol>``` for me. I have tried that before actually. It's not working on my setup for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved. There were empty string added before I paste my code in the VS. That was adding additional `<specialcharacter>` for me. I removed it by simply pasting in Notepad -> manually removed the empty strings and copy the code again to VS. Now, it is working as expected.